# iOS swift strings do not compare as equal

Tags: ios, swift, comparison

I have the following code in my application

```
    println("currentTitle : '" + btnDOW.currentTitle! + "'")
    println("gobj_DOWs[iobj_NearbyLocationsVM.DOWToUse].DOWName: '" + gobj_DOWs[iobj_NearbyLocationsVM.DOWToUse].DOWName + "'")

    if btnDOW.currentTitle!.uppercaseString != gobj_DOWs[iobj_NearbyLocationsVM.DOWToUse].DOWName.uppercaseString
    {
        //reload the data
        GPSLocationChanged()
    }
```

The println output from the two statements is as follows:

> currentTitle : 'Wednesday'
>
> gobj_DOWs[iobj_NearbyLocationsVM.DOWToUse].DOWName: 'Wednesday'

However, the values are not comparing as equal in my if statement. I know this because a breakpoint on the GPSLocationChanged line and the breakpoint is always hit.   Any idea as to why??

Comment: How are you certain the values aren't comparing as equal?

Comment: You should store the results of the intermediary strings before you print and test for equality. Those values may have changed between the print statement and the equality test, or the values being printed out could be different from the values actually being tested in a way that's difficult to notice.

Comment: The lines of code are exactly as they are in my application.  I println immediately before the if the statement so they could not have changed.  I know they are not comparing equal because the GPSLocationChanged function is executing.  I have put a breakpoint on that line of code and it is alway hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I changed the code as follows as now it seems to work.

```
    println("currentTitle : '" + btnDOW.currentTitle! + "'")
    ls_WorkTitle = btnDOW.currentTitle!


    println("gobj_DOWs[iobj_NearbyLocationsVM.DOWToUse].DOWName: '" + gobj_DOWs[iobj_NearbyLocationsVM.DOWToUse].DOWName + "'")
    ls_WorkDOWName = gobj_DOWs[iobj_NearbyLocationsVM.DOWToUse].DOWName

    //if btnDOW.currentTitle!.uppercaseString != gobj_DOWs[iobj_NearbyLocationsVM.DOWToUse].DOWName.uppercaseString

    if ls_WorkTitle.uppercaseString != ls_WorkDOWName.uppercaseString
    {
        //reload the data
        println("Dow Of Week Values are different")
        GPSLocationChanged()
    }
```

There should be nothing changing either of these values between the print lines and the if statement.  Why is it necessary for me to put these into new variables before I compare then?  That is pretty ridiculous.

This is my first experience with IOS development and so far and have to say it is pretty much at the bottom of the totem pole for development platforms and languages (Swift).